# vim/macvim plugins osx 10.7.4

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, macvim

Could you help me get plugins working for either macvim or the terminal vim?

What I have tried thus far:

To the desktop I `git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git`. I have attempted placing the files in `~/.vim`, where I created a folder named bundle and placed file nerdtree in there.

Alternatively I have gone to `/usr/share/vim/vim73` and placed all files in the their respective folders.
Using this method does work for NERDTree in the terminal vim, however it does not for other plugins.

Still no luck with getting this to work. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `NERD_tree` install details:

- Unzip the archive into your ~/.vim directory.
- That should put NERD_tree.vim in ~/.vim/plugin and NERD_tree.txt in ~/.vim/doc.

After installing, the `~/.vim` looks like this:

```
.vim/
├── doc
│   ├── NERD_tree.txt
│   └── tags
├── nerdtree_plugin
│   ├── exec_menuitem.vim
│   └── fs_menu.vim
├── plugin
│   └── NERD_tree.vim
└── syntax
    └── nerdtree.vim
```

Comment: super. i swear i tried something similar to this, but it didnt work. This time it did. Aswell for other plugins.
i also found another location that the plugins can be installed /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin
thankyou

Answer (score 5):

I use [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332). This allows you to put all you plugins in a separate directory making it very easy to manage. E.g. when using nerdtree which you can clone into a folder and do `git pull` when there is a update.

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
call pathogen#infect()
```

then, add nerdtree etc to the folder

```
~/.vim/bundle
```

that's all you need to do!

Comment: i was also reading about pathtogen, however I didnt quite understand how it works. do i also create a .vimrc file next to my .vim file ?

pathtogen would be good to use as i understand that it keeps everything uptodate. either way i am happy i now have a way to install plugins cheers

Comment: Nope, no just add `call pathogen#infect()` to your "normal" .vimrc`. Pathogen doesn't keep anything up-to-date, that you have to do by hand. `Pathogen` is just a way to keep everything organized. I have a bash-script that goes through all my gits under the `bundle` and does a `git pull` for each of them. Remember to upvote if the answer was helpful :-)

Comment: ahh wow, i actually understood this.
just to emphasize on this for anyone else whom might be interested:
-in the `~/.vim` folder create another folder called autoload aswell as bundle and within the autoload place the pathogen.vim file
-to locate the `.vimrc` open macvim then click edit/startup settings from the menu bar (this is a file that you can use to customize vim, for example type ":set number" to add the numberlines) thus to use pathtogen simple type `:call pathogen#infect()` on a separate line.
-then to add plugins simply place the entire git clone in the bundle folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this needs to be in:
~/.vim/plugin/...

From:
http://vim.runpaint.org/extending/extending-vim-with-scripts-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to do this

```
  git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/
```

So u can be sure that the plugin go in the right folder, otherwise git make nerdtree folder for you, and you must move the nertrees' content to your ~/.vim/

Comment: Luckily git does not clone overwriting non-empty folders!!